# How to pass exchange ID and originating route ID to a bean?

Tags: java, apache-camel

`Exchange` interface has `getExchangeId()` method which returns ID of an exchange. Is there a way to pass this value to a method of a bean when calling the bean from a route?

The same question is about ID of a route which originated an exchange. This value is returned by `getFromRouteId()` method of `Exchange` interface.

I know I could pass an `Exchange` object to the bean entirely. But it's undesirable to bind a bean to Camel API in my case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `@Simple` annotation bean parameter binding

```
   public void foo(@Simple("exchangeId") String id, 
                   @Simple("routeId") String routeId, 
                   Object body) { 
     ...
   }
```

Some links

- http://camel.apache.org/simple
- http://camel.apache.org/parameter-binding-annotations.html

Comment: Using Camel 3.0.0 it seems that this solution doesn't work. The following annotation does work though: `@Simple("${exchangeId}")`

Comment: See the migration guide, the annotation has moved, and you should also use `${exchangeId}` to refer to the function. The above is using the old syntax that is deprecated, even on 2.x.